How can I install a new OS on a boot looping tablet?
I have an older tablet that I used to use to read. I left it in my drawer for a few years and now I want to do something with it again. When I turned it on it was stuck in a boot loop. I decided to factory reset the tablet to see if that would work, and it did (kind of). The tablet booted into the "First time setup" wizard, and I went along with it. The setup runs smoothly up until the tablet needs to connect to a Wi-Fi network. A few seconds after connecting to a network it shows a "Checking for updates" screen before falling right back into a boot loop. Skipping the connecting to a network is not an option
The tablet is a Hurricane Surge and runs Android 7. I can't activate developer options while the tablet is in Setup Mode, and I can't complete the setup because it keeps boot looping after connecting to a network.
The device isn't showing up on ADB, I do have access to the internal storage when connecting it to my computer while it is in the setup mode.
I don't care much for keeping the OS as I want to install either a different version of android or something like PhoenixOS.
I've tried doing a factory reset, to no avail.
I tried connecting it to my computer to use ADB but it doesn't show up when running adb devices and I can't seem to find any designated USB driver for this specific Hurricane model.
I tried accessing the settings while in setup mode and while that did work, I still can't activate developer options. Tapping on the build number does nothing. (There is a small window when the tablet turns on where there is a developer options tab in settings but tapping on it just says something like: 'You don't have the required permissions' before kicking you out and disappearing.
Putting it into Fastboot or Recovery Mode also doesn't seem to do much, in Fastboot it doesn't show in ADB or explorer and same goes for Recovery Mode. It's also worth mentioning that when it is in Fastboot there is no way to get it out other than pressing a little reset button located inside a small hole in the side of the tablet (using a thin wire or SIM ejector)

Looks like there's not so much info about the device, I could only find a reference to the stock firmware on this site (MT6580 based). But other than that, I kind of doubt if the bootloader can be unlocked in the first place, or if there's a custom ROM for this device.
